# Determining which user is executing my Apache app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, passenger

On my Ubuntu server with apache2/rails 3.0.3 I'd like to know which user runs my app.

Documentation and a lot of sources on the net says that the owner of config/environnement.rb is the one running the app.

If I `ps -aux|grep apache`, I can only see processes with `www-data` as the owner. There is no passenger or ruby or rails processes.

How can I know for sure which user is running my rails app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ps aux | grep -i passenger` or if that doesn't result in anything, `ps aux | grep -i /application/directory/`

If it's running as a passenger app, this will return the Passenger processes. Specifically, you'll probably be looking for Passenger ApplicationSpawner: /your/app/public/

Comment: Ok but then, why does apache have trace errors about images he cannot read? I have images folders generated by paperclip with rwxr-w--- attributes owned by the rails user. Should apache also be executed with the rails user?

Comment: I'm running nginx in production, and it's owned by root. Passenger is owned by the rails user. Paperclip is writing with the correct permissions as it's a ruby process run through Passenger/Rails. Sounds like you need to hunt down some answers about Paperclip configuration.

Comment: Sylario - please note that the `passenger` process is **not** the process you're interested in.

Comment: @Sylario: Your permissions are no good.  The folders should be 750 (if apache belongs to the group that the files are owned by), or 755 otherwise.

Comment: i want them to be 755, with 750 apache cannot access images!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like rack may change the process name of your rails processes.  Mine show up as "Rack: /path/to/app".  Try `ps -ef | grep Rack`.

Answer (score 2):

Try `ps aux | grep -i rails` instead.

### Update

Heh, a flood of answers, cam reminded me - if you have a `config.ru` then your app will be a rack application.  If not then it'll be a rails application.  So either his or mine will work for you.

Comment: True that - grep for the application folder would work better. I'll update my answer.